# Generate PDF from Power Apps form including attachments

Tags: pdf-generation, powerapps, connector, powerapps-canvas

I need to convert the Power Apps form data (textbox, drop downs, checkbox - whatever user selects on form) including attachments files and images into one single PDF. So, ideally the generated PDF should have all metadata content added on form plus the content from all documents and images. For this, I need to use Muhimbi PDF conversion on-premise endpoint (as per client requirements). Since the endpoint is on premise, I need to develop an API wrapper/gateway in .NET Core.

So the solution will be :

1. Pass the data from Power Apps to custom connector
2. Custom connector will take the inputs as bytestream / datastream and will pass this to .NET Core API which will call Muhimbi endpoint.
3. This .NET Core API will give the generated PDF content as output back to custom connector (which will be used in Power Automate).

**My queries are -**

1. Is the above approach is fine or there is a better solution?
2. How to pass the data to .NET Core API via custom connector ?